# Android ScrollView Add a new Row

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I am a Newbie to Android/Java programming and i am even to bad to solve this problem. I just dont get what is wrong. I'll create a new Activity putting an Extra to the Intent and want to show the string inside of the scroll view! My app always shut down while starting this activity.

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_parcelable_text);

    dataTableScrollView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        dataListView = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_PARCELABLE_TEXT)+
                "\n";
    }else{
        dataListView += savedInstanceState.get(PARCELABLE_STRING)+
                "\n";
    }

    setAllDataToListView();
}

private void setAllDataToListView(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.
            LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View newListViewElement = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_parcelable_text, null);

    TextView newDataTextView = (TextView) newListViewElement.findViewById(R.id.scrollViewTextView);

    newDataTextView.setText(dataListView);

    dataTableScrollView.addView(newListViewElement, 0);
}
```

I just dont get what i am doing wrong!
And i can't find a proper answer.

Thank you in advance for your response!

Comment: Use intent.getExtras().getString(...) instead of intent.getStringExtra(...) and let me know if it works or crashes anyway...

Comment: I think you mean to use the onNewIntent method instead, there you get the intent directly.

Comment: Can you post the logcat output? I suspect R.id.scrollView1 to be a ScrollView and not a RelativeLayout

Comment: intent.getExtras().getString(...) still crashes. if i wouldn't instantiate any Item like RelativeLayout it would work.

Comment: I can't answer my own question i'll upload the file

Comment: But the Scroll View isn't the problem even if i change that it doesn't work

Comment: http://www.file-upload.net/download-8257588/Logcat.txt.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you put the activity class inside AndroidManifest.xml ? if no add it like this

```
<activity android:name="com.project.classname" />
```

and 
try to modify your code to this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_parcelable_text);

    dataTableScrollView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

   //Get values for intent when activity started for firsttime
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
   if (extras != null) 
    {
        //Get dataListView as String 
    dataListView    = extras.getString("dataListView");
    }

   //Get values on orientation 
   if( savedInstanceState != null )
    { 
       dataListView = savedInstanceState.getString("dataListView");
    }


   //Add extra String PARCELABLE_STRING
   dataListView += savedInstanceState.get(PARCELABLE_STRING)+"\n";


    setAllDataToListView();
}

//save info when screen orientation 
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

  outState.putString("dataListView",dataListView);
}   


private void setAllDataToListView(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.
            LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View newListViewElement = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_parcelable_text, null);

    TextView newDataTextView = (TextView) newListViewElement.findViewById(R.id.scrollViewTextView);

    newDataTextView.setText(dataListView);

    dataTableScrollView.addView(newListViewElement, 0);
}
```